# How can I find repeating characters in a string and remove them using data structures?

Tags: data-structures

How can you find repeating characters in a string and remove them and print the final string using data structures? Which data structure is the best suited for this? This was an interview question, I was not supposed to use for-loops or iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting each character as an element of a set, more precisely an ordered set, would automatically remove any duplicate character.

The string "Hello, World!" would then give you:

```
Set {
 H
 e
 l
 l # ignored
 o
 ,


 W
 o # ignored
 r
 l # ignored
 d
 !
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even I had done the same thing using set in python. But I would like to know if this is possible to be done by using any particular data structure. If so which data structure would that be?

Comment: @ArunT a set is a specific kind of data structure, so that answers the question

Comment: Thanks for the update on that, Could you share any link where I can learn more about the theoretical part of sets in data structures? It would be of great help. Thanks again.